# How to switch on the web camera in my dell laptop(Ubuntu OS)?

Tags: drivers

Eagerly waiting for my web camera to switch on.

How to switch on my web-cam which is not get switch on automatically ?

Comment: Does a program like `cheese` or Skype detect it?

Answer (score 0):

You can on your camera by downloading any software in Ubuntu store. The software I have been using are  "cheese webcam booth" "camera" etc.